# Is the series of object clauses used correctly in the following sentence?

Tags: grammar, clauses

> She then told them she was 52, living alone, and had no doubt there was something very malicious and dangerous in her house, and that she dared not go back inside.

How many object clauses are there? Two or four? Do they all need to be preceded by "that"?

Comment: It's all correct.  Putting back everything that's been optionally deleted, you get something like _She then told them (that) she was 52, (and that) she was living alone, and (that) she had no doubt (that) there was something (that was) very malicious and (that) was very dangerous in her home, and that she dared not go back inside_. Count the clauses by counting the verbs: _told, was 52, was living, had, there was, was malicious, was dangerous, dared, go_. I count 9, most of them conjoined _that_ clauses, plus the infinitive complement clause of _dare not_.

Comment: You don't need the first *and* (but it's fine to leave it in).

Answer (score 1):

She then told them

1 she

1' was

1'' 52,

1'' living alone,

1' (and) had no doubt there was something very malicious and dangerous in her house,

1 (and) that she dared not go back inside.

The grammar is just fine, (1 she) could also be preceded by *that*. The second *that* marking dependent clause *she dared not go back inside* seems necessary to mark the fact that it is not part of the noun phrase headed by *doubt*, though even with it, it is technically ambiguous whether we are meant to understand that:

*she had no doubt that she dared not go back inside*

OR

*She then told them that she dared not go back inside*

Assuming the latter, there is a coordination at the (1), (1') and (1'') level. The (1'') level coordination is not marked.

If we take object clauses to be clauses allowed by other verbs, and take clauses generally to be constructions headed by a single verb, the object clauses are:

1. Headed by *was*, allowed by *told*, subject (1 she) by coordination

> *was 52, living alone*

2. Headed by *had*, allowed by *told*, subject (1 she) by coordination

> *(and) had no doubt there was something very malicious and dangerous in the house*

3. Headed by *dared*, allowed by *told*

> *(and) that she dared not go back inside*

4. Headed by *living*, allowed by *was*, understood subject (1 she)

> *living alone*

5. Headed by *go* allowed by *dared*, understood subject (she - subject of *dared*)

> *go back inside*

There is one additional clause in the sentence:

6. Headed by *was*, dependent in noun phrase headed by *doubt*

> *there was something very malicious in her house*